# Why does the function run when there are no elements found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code, however if the `input.formdate` is not found it will still run the `getDateFormat` function. This doesn't make sense to me.

Does anyone know the reason?

```
$(function() {
    $("input.formdate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: getDateFormat()
    });
});

function getDateFormat()
{
    var format = 'DMY';

    if (document.edit_form && document.edit_form.date_format)
        format = document.edit_form.date_format.value;

    if (format = "DMY")
        return "dd-mm-yy";
    else
        return "mm-dd-yy";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The getDateFormat function is run as soon as Javascript is parsed because it is within an object literal notation.

Your expression is evaluated as

```
$(function() {
    $("input.formdate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: <RESULT_FROM_CALLING_getDateFormat()>
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

***Old Answer:***
*(based on mis-understanding of question - see comments)*
Because you're calling the function and passing its result, instead of what you should be doing: passing a reference to the function (i.e. treating it as a variable).

Do this:

```
$(function() {
    $("input.formdate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: getDateFormat
    });
});
```

---

***Update:***
After checking the jQuery UI DatePicker API, you need to pass a string to dateFormat.
If you don't want your function to execute unless there is at least one input with a class of formdate, you need to do this:

```
if ( $('input.formdate').length > 0 )
{
    $("input.formdate").datepicker
    (
        { changeMonth: true
        , changeYear: true
        , dateFormat: getDateFormat()
        }
    );
}
```

Alternatively, you could do it with an inline if:

```
$("input.formdate").datepicker
(
    { changeMonth: true
    , changeYear: true
    , dateFormat:
        $('input.formdate').length > 0 ? getDateFormat() : 'dd-mm-yy'
    }
);
```

Though it's debatable if that's more or less readable.

(There's probably still a shorter way than that, but I have to go now.)

Comment: +1 correct answer, though I think "passing a reference to the function itself" would be slightly clearer "passing the value of the function"

Comment: Agreed, that wording wasn't great; I've updated it and incorporated your suggestion. :)

Comment: passing a reference to the function does't work. It just returns empty string when I select a date. hmmm????

Comment: Well that's not what you asked - you asked why it was being called whether elements are found or not. Looking at the actual API docs, it seems dateFormat is a string argument not a function, so I'll have to update my answer...

Comment: Yeah i thought so. Thanks for the response though Peter. Helped me understand it better. Cheers.